# Change Objective-C rootViewController to SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swiftui

I have a project built with React Native where for some feature I change the rootViewController from React Native to a Storyboard with the following code:

```objectivec
- (void) goToNativeView
{
  UIViewController *vc = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil].instantiateInitialViewController;
  self.window.rootViewController = vc;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

We want to get rid of Storyboard and use SwiftUI instead, but I wasn't able to find a way of doing the same thing we do with Storyboard but with SwiftUI

I want to know if it's possible and, if it is, how to do it

Comment: You need `UIHostingController`

Comment: SwiftUI, as its name says, needs Swift. Thus, you have to write Swift code, Objective-C won't work